# Как убрать расстояние между блоками?

Tags: css

Подайте, пожалуйста идею как можно убрать расстояние между блоками? Чтобы третий блок примыкал к первому. Из-за свойств float 3-й начинается после второго. И не могу придумать как сделать, чтобы он был выше.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если найденное решение отличается от ответов других участников, опубликуйте его в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная проблема оказалась не связана с CSS. В файле list.phtml нужно было поменять 3 и 4 блоки местами и всё стало на места.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить два div-а. Левый и правый. А уже в них размещать блоки block.

CSS

```
div.left {float:left; width:300px; overflow:hidden}
div.right {float:left; width:300px; overflow:hidden}
div.block1 {float:left; width:300px; height:100px; background-color:#f00}
div.block2 {float:left; width:300px; height:200px; background-color:#00f}
div.block3 {float:left; width:300px; height:200px; background-color:#0f0}
div.block4 {float:left; width:300px; height:100px; background-color:#000}
```

HTML

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="block1">

    </div>
    <div class="block3">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="block2">

    </div>
    <div class="block4">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению этого не сделать так как блоки из разных модулей и пока не представляю возможно ли их разделить в два дива, так как общего хмл файла нет...

Answer (score 0):

Свойство float не влияет на разрыв между 1 и 3 блоком.
Какие-то другие свойства установлены?

Вот скриншот результата работы аналогичного кода:
[image: Пример работы свойства]

Comment: Интересно получается, дело в том, что у меня так же всё поставлено, единственно есть margin-bottom: 5px. Но это не влияет на такой большой разрыв, там именно связь, что третий блок пляшет от того где заканчивается низ второго. Возможно дело в том, что в вашем примере указаны высоты, а у меня блоки как-бы резиновые. http://agestor.com/pharmacy/capsules.html?mode=list

Comment: Указанная высота в данном случае не имеет значения. Можно заполнить Block2 текстом, чтобы его высота стала больше, чем у Block3. Результат будет тот же.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, ссылку выше, там видно, что все css стоят эдентичные (единственно есть ещё margin, но они дают всего несколько пикселей), но при этом всё рвыно образуется отстут...

Comment: По ссылке, которую вы привели, такой ситуации нет.

Comment: А вы смотрели тот товар где старая зачёркнутая цена и новая? Там блок №2 стал выше и появился разрыв.

Comment: Там другой порядок вывода блоков. Block3 у вас справа, а Block4 слева. Если поменяете местами порядок вывода блоков 3 и 4, то разрыв исчезнет.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Я так понимаю это должен искать уже hml и phtml файлах, чтобы поменять порядок?

Comment: Спасибо всем за труд и помощь!!! Нашёл, дело было в порядке написания блоков в файле модуля выводящего их.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Успехов в настройке! :)